# how to get json file and use it after request returns not before ?

Tags: jquery, json

At some point i want to get json file and use data inside it so i do this :

```
var obj = $.getJSON( "package.json", function() {
  console.log( " i have json now !" );
})
alert(obj[0].email);
//// i use obj here but it keep giving me undefined , i think it's about non blocking way of get json but i donna know how to make it right
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = $.getJSON( "package.json", function(data) {
  console.log( " i have json now !" );
});

obj.done(function(data) {
  alert(data[0].email);
});
```

This will alert when it's done getting the data.